# How to get all child with same tag from CCLayer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

Actually i am working with cocos2d Game. I am using CCLayer for particular scene. now there are so many buttons means CCMenuitems are available. I want to disable that all menuitems having same tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is but the way I would do is by putting all the children into an array. Then iterate trough the array:

```
WhateverYouNeed *thingInArray;
CCArray *theArray = [self children];
for thingInArray in theArray {
  if ([thingInArray tag] == whateverTheTagIs) 
    do some stuff to thingInArray
}
```